# Connect to AWS RDS database from EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, aws-security-group

I'm student and I start to explore AWS with free tier EC2 and RDS. I have a spring boot app and this is my application.properties

```
server.port=8080
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://tiktok.cdo6k4mey5el.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/tiktok
spring.datasource.username=admin
spring.datasource.password=**********
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

When running application on my local laptop, I can connect to the RDS database and can perform CRUD actions there! However, when I deploy my app to EC2, I can not connect to MySQL on RDS!
These are my security groups for EC2 [image]
[image]

An this is how I set the inbound with outbound on RDS

[image]
[image]
[image]

Could anyone have experience this before or found out what I did wrong to help me figure it out? Thank you!

Comment: A couple of things worth noting: you probably shouldn't post the RDS endpoint like that since you've set it as publicly available, meaning anyone in the world can access it (hence the access from your computer works). I would argue you should make sure to limit access to your EC2 instance as well (right now anyone can access it). Last, but not the least, your RDS security group allows outbound access TO the IP address of the EC2 instance, while in fact it should be inbound, i.e, allow access FROM the IP address of the EC2 instance.

Comment: Instructions are [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.RDSSecurityGroups.html#Overview.RDSSecurityGroups.Scenarios). The RDS security group should allow inbound traffic from the EC2 instance security group (not from its IP). If your laptop needs SSH access to EC2 and MySQL access to RDS then allow the relevant traffic on the two security groups *but* restrict it to your home IP address (do not allow 0.0.0.0/0 inbound on anything that is not intended for public access).

Comment: Hi, thanks much Marko! I'm starting learning and using the free tier, I will delete my database very soon after 2 weeks of my courses. I have finally able to connect the RDS by updating the inbound.

Comment: I appreciate your help Jarmod, thanks for the documents, I will follow that setup for the next time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is related to your **Inbound rules on the database**, which are only accepting connections from your laptop and from the Database (yes, from itself!).

The typical configuration is:

- A Security Group on the EC2 instance (`EC2-SG`) that permits:

  - Inbound: SSH (port 22) from your laptop on the Internet
  - Outbound: All Traffic
- A Security Group on the RDS instance (`DB-SG`) that permits:

  - Inbound: access on the database port from `EC2-SG` and also from your laptop
  - Outbound rules not required

That is, `DB-SG` should specifically reference `EC2-SG`. This way, any EC2 instance that is assigned the `EC2-SG` security group will be permitted to access the database.

If you are running a web application on the EC2 instance, then also add the necessary inbound ports (eg 80, 443).

In general, try to avoid mentioning specific IP addresses in Security Groups unless it is for a resource on the Internet.

In looking at your screenshots, I suspect that the Outbound rules on the EC2 instance (which are not shown) might be the problem. It should be allowing All Traffic outbound.

Comment: I truly appreciate your kind help John I followed your guidelines and it works now, with this set up then only my laptop and my my EC2 instant could access to it right?

Comment: Yes, this configuration only allows your laptop to access the EC2 instance, and only the EC2 instance is permitted access to the Database.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using public RDS so whitelisting the private ip in DB Security Group doesn’t helpful. I am assuming another ip in DB security group is your laptop public ip. I would suggest to whitelist the EC2 security group in RDS security group for 3306(if it is mysql). This should solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks Saurabh for your instructions!

Answer (score 1):

In your use case, `Inbound` rules are to be focused on:-

Security Group for the `EC2` instance:

- `Inbound`  :
  SSH (port 22) from your Laptop's IP Address.
  Port 443 or 80 based on your application's availability to 0.0.0.0
- `Outbound` :
  All Traffic

Security Group for the `RDS` instance:

- `Inbound`  :
  IP Address of EC2 instance towards database port / You may add security group of EC2 as well.
  Access from your laptop's IP Address towards db port.
- `Outbound` :
  You may keep it default/empty since that is not required in this case.

Comment: Thanks Deep! I set up my base on your recommendation, and it works for me now!